# Prevent download files from URL

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I've Blazor Application (Blazor Server) with side menu. When you click on one of these menus, you will open PDF file based on specific privilege (when clicks on href).

My question :- what if someone changes the URL manually and replace it by the file URL, how I can get this URL or prevent unauthorized user from downloading this file ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to create a controller to download file, so you can control the download before it starts.

Something like:

```html
<a href="/files/download?name=myfile.pdf">My File</a>
```

In this case the **FilesController** will have a `Download` method and inside this method you can check the authorization process.

Answer (score 0):

```
public FileResult DownloadFile()
{
    // logic to allow/disallow users from downloading
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"pathtofile"); // or any other source
    string fileName = "nameWithExtension";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

While link to this method in controller can be presented to end users

Comment: Hi Sarang, Since my files are located in the client project (not in server side),I've created the controller inside the client project, So , How I can call and pass parameters to this controller in Blazor ? can you give ma an example about this

Comment: You need to have a link between server and client. To use this technique the server have to be the _servant_  of the files.

Comment: Hi Guys, there is a way to open the return file result instead of download it ?

Comment: You can verify user and then present the link to open or download